# How to measure bundle size react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a production app that I want to optimize for startup time, how would you measure debug and prod bundle sizes?

Also, how could you measure startup time? I am currently doing this manually.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For bundle size, you can use [react-native-bundle-visualizer](https://github.com/IjzerenHein/react-native-bundle-visualizer) or use one of the library size plugins for IDEs such as Wix's [import-cost](https://github.com/wix/import-cost).

As for startup time, profiling your app is important to do separately on each platform (since different things can influence it). The [performance section](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html) of the react-native documentation gives a few options such as using `systrace` on Android and then opening the trace in chrome to get a better view of what's going on.

Comment: I believe I could not use it because it's based on Haul and I am taking advantage of the haste module system.